# Asking my prof. whether he is affected by the hurricane in Texas,

Tags: email

I and our security guards have not heard from nor seen a prof. of mine who I do research for.  We do know that he is from Texas, but we are unsure of his exact hometown.

How can I email to ask about his and his family's safety without overstepping any boundaries?

Comment: Would you be wondering about him not answering your research-related emails if the situation in Texas wouldn't be as it is?

Comment: If he's on vacation, someone in your/his department should know, such as administration, head of department, close colleagues. Unless he's going on vacation every now and then and doesn't spend much time at the institute. Check with them maybe? Just mention that you are worried, given the situation in his home state/city/whatever

Comment: Ask. He'll appreciate the gesture. Do not add that you are asking because you haven't heard from him.

Comment: I sent an mail to my supervisors the minute I heard about Paris' shootings. Nothing wrong with that, IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to ask. Like a commenter mentioned, probably better to not add that it's because you haven't heard from him on a particular issue (i.e. not "Did you forget those TPS reports, or are you affected by a hurricane?").

Some things to consider:

1. It's possible you haven't heard because he is directly affected: stranded, injured, hospitalized, dead.
2. However, it is also possible you haven't heard because his family is directly affected. He might be searching frantically for them, trying to make contact, helping in some way, etc.
3. Lastly, it's possible that the situation is completely unrelated.

With all of those things in mind, especially #2, a polite show of concern is certainly appropriate, without any attached expectations or requests. Something along the lines of "Since I know you have ties to Texas, I hope you and your family and friends are safe." Even if it turns out he isn't from the Houston/gulf coast area, there is a reasonable probability that he could know someone in the area and would appreciate the sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor may be your superior, but he's also a person (and a co-worker in some sense). There is nothing wrong with writing an email that says that you are hoping that he's ok given that you know that he's from Texas. Wouldn't *you* appreciate if one of your colleagues write such an email?